# Select rows, where 3 columns have the same values

Tags: postgresql

I have a structure like this:

```
 col0 col1 col2 col3
 1    1    1    1
 1    1    1    2
 1    1    1    3
 1    2    1    1
 1    2    3    1
 2    3    4    5
 2    3    4    9
```

I now want to select all rows, that match other rows on the first three columns, so the result of this query using the sample data would be:

```
 col0 col1 col2 col3
 1    1    1    1
 1    1    1    2
 1    1    1    3
 2    3    4    5
 2    3    4    9
```

How can I achieve this, I'm kinda stuck at the early beginning...

Thanks in advance!
Alex

Update: Clearified the question. Thanks Erwin.

Comment: Why are the two rows with `2 3 4 5` and `2 3 4 9` in the results? `2` is not equal to `3`.

Comment: Your demo result makes it look like you want to find rows that match *another row* on the first three columns. And your description matches *neither* your result *nor* the accepted answer. Please clarify by editing the question.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
  col0
  ,col1
  ,col2
  ,col3
FROM
  foo
WHERE
  col0 = col1
  and col0 = col2;
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. It was so simple - thank you!

Comment: Well it does not do it, unfortunately.

Comment: @MikeFal the OP has edited the question so he needs something else, not the first description (which you had answered.)

Answer (score 3):

I somehow managed to find a solution, though I do not know if there is a more performant variant:

```
select
  distinct a.col0, a.col1, a.col2, a.col3
from foo a, foo b
where
  a.col0 = b.col0 and 
  a.col1 = b.col1 and 
  a.col2 = b.col2 and 
  a.col3 != b.col3
order by
   a.col0,
   a.col1,
   a.col2;
```

Answer (score 1):

We have to find all touples (col0, col1, col3) that occour at least twice  and then get all rows that match the tuples.

Solution A: col0, col1 and col2 do not contain any NULLs

```
SELECT * FROM 
foo 
WHERE (col0, col1, col2) IN (
        SELECT col0, col1, col2 
        FROM foo 
        GROUP BY  1,2,3 
        HAVING  count(*)>1
        );
```

Solution B: NULLs are allowed:

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM foo f 
JOIN (
        SELECT col0, col1, col2
        FROM foo
        GROUP BY  1,2,3
        HAVING  count(*)>1
        ) q 
ON (
    f.col0 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM q.col0
    AND f.col1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM q.col1
    AND f.col2 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM q.col2
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

I find [common table expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-with.html) (CTEs) to be tremendously helpful in breaking a query like this down into blocks that are easier for me wrap my brain around.

Here is your problem using a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT col0, col1, col2
  FROM foo)

SELECT foo.*
FROM foo
  INNER JOIN cte
    ON      cte.col0 = foo.col0
        AND cte.col1 = foo.col1
        AND cte.col2 = foo.col2
```

Here's the SQL Fiddle for it:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/c4c96/2/0

Comment: There have to be two or more rows with the same values. As it stands, your query will return every row (since a row will always match itself). See the questioner's own answer.

Comment: update the fiddle please, it does not works anymore